# How to remove single quotes from expression?

Tags: php

I have an hindi expression ‘बैंक धोखाधड़ी के कानूनी पहलुओं‘ from which i am trying to escape the single quotes before entering into database but mysql_real_escape_string and addslashes is not working, what can be done in this case?

When i am replacing the ‘ in the original expression with ' and performing the operation, addslashes are working. are they different in any way?

Comment: They look like unicode characters to me. Can you try using `htmlentities` on it and update your question?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` for two reasons. 1. You shouldn't use `mysql` functions, because they are deprecated. 2. If you use prepared statements with parameters, you don't need to escape strings at all.

Comment: @Aniket htmlentities is not displayinging anything

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for your suggestion. i won't use it

Comment: Why do you want to escape those quotes if they're not the kind of quotes that count as MySQL special-character quotes to begin with?

Comment: @deceze because the data is not entering beyond these quotes

Comment: "Not beyond"? So the first part of the string is getting into the database, but it's cut off after the quote? Then you're not handling encodings correctly. If quotes wouldn't be escaped correctly, you'd get a syntax error instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regular expression I have tested to be working on your scenario:-

```
(?<mystring>[^\u2018]+[^\u0000-\u007F\u2018$]+)
```

You will get the result as named capture group 'mystring' as in the regular expression.

Your string is Unicode. The quotes are unicode character "\u2018"
.You can use the above regular expression to match the required string and then use that string (your string between unicode quotes) to do the insert.

HTH!